# How to simulate an event in select box on load page?

Tags: javascript, select

How to simulate an event in select box on load page?

For example in this page http://www.chicagocomputers.com.ar/oa/ourpcs2.php?ref=AMDAM3002
I need to show the Gabinete product price automaticaly

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery-Min. So you can:

```
jQuery(selector_for_element).trigger('your_event_name');
```

Have fun. Good night.